# Compare two JSONArrays and get difference in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare, logic

I'm trying to compare two arrays & find out elements where even one key-value is different. I have same keys in both arrays.

The below code is comparing only for one key. Where am I going wrong? how can I make it compare for all keys?

My constraint being that the keys need to be dynamically compared it can't be hardcoded.

```
a = [{ value:"4a55eff3-1e0d-4a81-9105-3ddd7521d642", display:"1"}, { value:"644838b3-604d-4899-8b78-09e4799f586f", display:"2"}, { value:"b6ee537a-375c-45bd-b9d4-4dd84a75041d", display:"3"}, { value:"e97339e1-939d-47ab-974c-1b68c9cfb536", display:"4"},  { value:"a63a6f77-c637-454e-abf2-dfb9b543af6c", display:"Ryan"}]
b = [{ value:"4a55eff3-1e0d-4a81-9105-3ddd7521d642", display:"Jamsheer"}, { value:"644838b3-604d-4899-8b78-09e4799f586f", display:"Muhammed"}, { value:"b6ee537a-375c-45bd-b9d4-4dd84a75041d", display:"Ravi"}, { value:"e97339e1-939d-47ab-974c-1b68c9cfb536", display:"Ajmal"}]

function  comparer(arr) {
    return function (a) {
      return arr.filter(function (b) {
        for(key in b){
            console.log(key)
            return b[key] == a[key];
        }
      }).length == 0;
    }
  }
  

var onlyInA = a.filter(comparer(b));

console.log(onlyInA);
```

Comment: you want every object in array 'a' to be compared with every object in array 'b' ?

Comment: @AyushMaheshwari yes.. and to be compared for all key values

Comment: You're probably better off using `!arr.some()` instead of `arr.filter().length == 0` for the comparison.